# How to calculate contour integration of multivalued functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I have a question about contour integral of the multivalude function. The question is from paper [arXiv:1211.6767](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6767) (page 6-7).

I want to calculate the Fourier transformation of a muti-valued function $f$
$$G(\omega,\mathbf{k})=\int dt d^{d-1}\mathbf{x} f(t,\mathbf{x})
e^{i\omega t-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}$$
with condition that 
$$\omega>0,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\omega^2-\mathbf{k}^2>0$$
so that we can deform the contour from the green one to the red one.
Function $f$ is given by
$$ f(t,\mathbf{x})=
 \big(\frac{-1}{t^2-\mathbf{x}^2-i\epsilon t}\big)^\Delta
$$
For $t<0$, $f$ can be written as
$$ f(t,\mathbf{x})=
\frac{e^{i\pi \Delta}}{ \big(t^2-x^2\big)^\Delta}
$$

For $t>0$, $f$ can be written as
$$ f(t,\mathbf{x})=
\frac{e^{-i\pi \Delta}}{ \big(t^2-x^2\big)^\Delta}
$$

First I need to write down the function on the four legs, $1,2,3,4$
On the leg 1, since $t<0$, we should have

$$ f_1(t,\mathbf{x})=
\frac{e^{i\pi \Delta}}{ \big(t^2-x^2\big)^\Delta}
$$
From leg 1 to leg 2, we need
$$(t+|x|)\rightarrow(t+|x|)e^{2\pi i} $$
$$ f_2(t,\mathbf{x})=
\frac{e^{-i\pi \Delta}}{ \big(t^2-x^2\big)^\Delta}
$$
On the leg 4, since $t>0$, we should have

$$ f_4(t,\mathbf{x})=
\frac{e^{-i\pi \Delta}}{ \big(t^2-x^2\big)^\Delta}
$$
From leg 4 to leg 3, we need
$$(t-|x|)\rightarrow(t+|x|)e^{-2\pi i} $$

$$ f_3(t,\mathbf{x})=
\frac{e^{i\pi \Delta}}{ \big(t^2-x^2\big)^\Delta}
$$

Combining the above result, we have
$$G(\omega,\mathbf{k})=(e^{-i \pi \Delta}-e^{+i \pi \Delta})
\int d^{d-1}\mathbf{x} \int^\infty_{|x|} dt
\frac{e^{i\omega t-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} }{(t^2-\mathbf{x}^2)^\Delta} \\
+(e^{+i \pi \Delta}-e^{-i \pi \Delta})
\int d^{d-1}\mathbf{x} \int^\infty_{|x|} dt
\frac{e^{-i\omega t-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} }{(t^2-\mathbf{x}^2)^\Delta}$$

But the authors' result is quite different
$$G(\omega,\mathbf{k})=2(e^{i \pi \Delta}-e^{-i \pi \Delta})
\int d^{d-1}\mathbf{x} \int^\infty_{|x|} dt
\frac{e^{i\omega t-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} }{(t^2-\mathbf{x}^2)^\Delta} $$